# What prevents Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll from calling the specified Action?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Take this segment.

```
IEnumerable<Task> tasks = CreateTierCleanupTasks();
if (tasks.Count() > 0) {
    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks.ToArray(), OnTierCleanupCompleted,
        m_CancellationTokenSource.Token,
        TaskContinuationOptions.None,
        m_TaskScheduler);
    Array.ForEach(tasks.ToArray(), (t) => t.Start()); 
    OnTierCleanupStarted();
}
```

And here is the specified Action.

```
private void OnTierCleanupCompleted(Task[] tasks) {
    if (tasks.All(task => task.IsCompleted) && TierCleanupCompleted != null) {
        TierCleanupCompleted(this, new EventArgs());
    }
    RunTierData();
}
```

Now in a test run, usually there are 5 tasks that are created, and they all run correctly. I put a `Debug.WriteLine("Task Return");` at the end of the function body to verify each task returns accordingly. The Action specified for ContinueWhenAll is *never* fired. I cannot figure out why. I thought the behavior of ContinueWhenAll would trigger the Action when all the specified Actions have returned (ie. completed).

What would prevent ContinueWhenAll from firing the Action?

Edit, here is the method that creates the tasks:

```
private IEnumerable<Task> CreateTierCleanupTasks() {
    using (FaultTrackObjectContext context = new FaultTrackObjectContext(this.TierInformation.EntityConnectionString)) {
        foreach (TeamCollection collection in context.TeamCollections.ToArray()) {
            yield return new Task(DeleteTeamCollection, collection.ID, m_CancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that in your code, `OnTierCleanupCompleted()` could be called **before** `OnTierCleanupStarted()` (if it worked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are iterating over the result of `CreateTierCleanupTasks()` several times. And each time, it creates a new set of `Task`s. So you are waiting on some tasks, but starting different ones.

Your code should look like this:

```
Task[] tasks = CreateTierCleanupTasks().ToArray();
if (tasks.Length > 0) {
    Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, OnTierCleanupCompleted,
        m_CancellationTokenSource.Token,
        TaskContinuationOptions.None,
        m_TaskScheduler);
    OnTierCleanupStarted();
    Array.ForEach(tasks, (t) => t.Start()); 
}
```